# Mirror method using arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am writing a "Mirror" method which duplicate the message backward, and add to the original ArrayList if the size is even.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> mirror(ArrayList<Integer> mr) {
    if (mr.size() % 2 == 0) {

        for (int i = mr.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            mr.add(mr.get(i));
        }
    }
    return mr;
}
```

This one does not give 1 though.
e.g.

```
[1,2,3,4]->[1,2,3,4,4,3,2]
```

If i>0 is changed to i>=0, then

```
[1,2,3,4]-> [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you calling mirror?

When I changed `i > 0` to `i >= 0` I get the results you're expecting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
    System.out.println(mirror(list));
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> mirror(ArrayList<Integer> mr) {
    if (mr.size() % 2 == 0) {
        for (int i = mr.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mr.add(mr.get(i));
        }
    }
    return mr;
}
```

Results:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]

### Update

Actually why check if it's an even sized list?  Just mirror any size.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    System.out.println(mirror(list));
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> mirror(ArrayList<Integer> mr) {
    for (int i = mr.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        mr.add(mr.get(i));
    }

    return mr;
}
```

Results:

[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]

Comment: @share1er80 Oh , ok . What I put in my main is System.out.println(object.mirror(lst)) instead of a for loop ..

Comment: @bslqy Glad to have helped :-). If you found that my answer helped your issue, kindly click the check mark for my answer so your question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this:

- Check if list size is even
- Make a copy of the original list
- Reverse the copy
- Add the reversed copy to the original list

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Snippet {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> mirror(ArrayList<Integer> mr) {

        if (mr.size() % 2 == 0) {

            ArrayList<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>();
            copy.addAll(mr); // Copy original list
            Collections.reverse(copy); // Reverse copy
            mr.addAll(copy); // Append reversed copy to original list
        }
        return mr;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lst.add(1);
        lst.add(2);
        lst.add(3);
        lst.add(4);

        lst = mirror(lst);
        for(Integer n : lst) {
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays or any collections have 0 as a index for first element. When you say `i>0` then it actually skips 1st element of the array i.e 1 in your case.

Comment: But I cannot put i=0 in the condition though. so should I just mannually add it?

Comment: The condition should be `i>=0`. `i=0` is invalid as it would be initialization and you already did initialized **i** with statement `int i = mr.size() - 1`.

Comment: Below is the format of for loop in java:
`for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update)
{
   //Statements
}`

Comment: Thanks. I figured out my main function has problem.  I put  System.out.println(object.mirror(lst)) instead of a for loop to print out.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution using the existing JDK methods:

```
public static <E, T extends List<E>> T mirror(T mr) {
    int size = mr.size();
    mr.addAll(mr.subList(0, size));
    Collections.reverse(mr.subList(size, size*2));
    return mr;
}
```

Note that now the method is much more generic: it can work with any mutable list type (not only `ArrayList`) and any list elements type (not only `Integer`).